# i have 3 tables in sql how to get data from last table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have table relationship as shown in below pic

[image]

i have tables like this

1. company

### company_id  +  company_name

```
12             ibm

13              hp
```

2. **skills**

### skills_id  +  company_id

```
 41            12

 42             13
```

3. **skills_sets**

### id     +      skills_id      +   skills

```
 1             41             php

 2             42             java
```

my question is how to get **php** and **java** using join?

Comment: What is your expected output ? Give us an idea in tabular format. Otherwise it's confusing where to start from.

Comment: php and java from skills_sets table

Comment: @Sumit patel , same format as shown above contains two fields:skills_id,company_id

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry, i did not get anything from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ss.skills
FROM company c
LEFT JOIN skills s ON c.company_id = s.company_id
LEFT JOIN skills_sets ss ON s.skills_id = ss.skills_id
```

If You need to select exactly only "php" and "java" You need to add a "WHERE" condition:

```
SELECT ss.skills
FROM company c
LEFT JOIN skills s ON c.company_id = s.company_id
LEFT JOIN skills_sets ss ON s.skills_id = ss.skills_id
WHERE ss.skills IN ('php', 'java')
```

If some explanations needed check the documentation on sql alias and join.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT company_name, skills
  FROM company
       NATURAL JOIN skills_sets
       NATURAL JOIN skills;
```

Comment: sir this the most optimized and good query i have ever came across, sorry i have only one upvote . thank you :)